# C++ Nested Validation loop

Tags: c++

My teacher would like me to put a "nested validation loop around the player's choice. That keeps looping until they enter valid input (1, 2, or 3)." I am having trouble getting anything to work could I get some pointers, please and thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Keaton Graffis 12/28/2015

int main()
{
    int seed = time(0);
    srand(seed);
    char playAgain;
    int playerChoice, aiChoice, win = 0, tie = 0, lose = 0;
    do
    {
        cout << "Lets play a game of rock paper scissors.\n";
        cout << "Enter a 1 for sccisors a 2 for rock or a 3 for paper: ";

        // Generates outcomes of the players choice
        cin >> playerChoice;
        if (playerChoice == 1)
        {
            cout << "You picked Rock!\n";
        }
        else if (playerChoice == 2)
        {
            cout << "You picked Paper!\n";
        }
        else if (playerChoice == 3)
        {
            cout << "You picked Scissors!\n";
        }

        // gentrate the computers choices
        int aiChoice = rand() % 3 + 1;

        if (aiChoice == 1)
        {
            cout << "The computer chose Rock!\n";
        }

        else if (aiChoice == 2)
        {
            cout << "The computer chose Paper!\n";
        }
        else if (aiChoice == 3)
        {
            cout << "The computer chose Scissors!\n";
        }

        // Determines wins, ties and loses
        if (playerChoice == 1 && aiChoice == 1) {
            cout << "Rock meets Rock its a tie!" << endl;
            tie++;
        }
        else if (playerChoice == 1 && aiChoice == 2)
        {
            cout << "Rock is covered by Paper the computer wins!." << endl;
            lose++;
        }
        else if (playerChoice == 1 && aiChoice == 3)
        {
            cout << "Rock crushes Scissors you win!" << endl;
            win++;
        }
        else if (playerChoice == 2 && aiChoice == 1)
        {
            cout << "Paper covers Rock you win!" << endl;
            win++;
        }
        else if (playerChoice == 2 && aiChoice == 2)
        {
            cout << "Paper meets Paper its a tie!" << endl;
            tie++;
        }
        else if (playerChoice == 2 && aiChoice == 3)
        {
            cout << "Paper is cut by Scissors the computer wins!" << endl;
            lose++;
        }
        else if (playerChoice == 3 && aiChoice == 1)
        {
            cout << "Scissors are crushed by Rock computer wins!" << endl;
            lose++;
        }
        else if (playerChoice == 3 && aiChoice == 2)
        {
            cout << "Scissors cuts Paper you win!" << endl;
            win++;
        }
        else if (playerChoice == 3 && aiChoice == 3)
        {
            cout << "Scissors meet Scissors its a tie!" << endl;
            tie++;
        }

        // Outputs wins, ties and loses 
        cout << "Wins: " << win << endl;
        cout << "Ties:" << tie << endl;
        cout << "Losses:" << lose << endl;
        cout << "Would you like to play again? Y/N" << endl;
        cin >> playAgain;
        system("CLS");
        // Allow user to play again
    } while (playAgain == 'Y' || playAgain == 'y');
}
```

Comment: And what happens when `playerChoice` is not `1`, `2` or `3`? Should you not have an `else` statement to handle that case?

Comment: That is what I wanted to do but he said to use a loop that just keeps repeating the cout statement "Enter a 1 for scissors ...." and keeps looking at the if/else statements from there.

Comment: @frodo12311 See answer below.

Comment: Yes a loop is alright, but you still need to handle the case when the input is not the one your program expects. What should happen if the input is e.g. `5`? You can't just continue like it's alright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can throw a while loop over the block of code that reads in the input and break from the loop when you receive valid input.

```
int choice;
bool valid = false;

while(!valid) {
    cout << "Enter a 1 for scissors, 2 for rock, 3 for paper" << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    if(choice == 1 || choice == 2 || choice == 3) 
        valid = true;
}
```